# METHOD concept program in c# is not working

Tags: c#

```
using System;
class Methodcalling
{

    public int Values(int num1, int num2)
    {

        if (num1 > num2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("num2 is large ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("num1 is big");
        }
    }
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int a, b;
        Methodcalling m = new Methodcalling();


        Console.WriteLine("enter a no.:");
        a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
        Console.WriteLine("enter a no.:");
        b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

        int result = m.Values(a, b);

    }

}
```

> ERROR:'Methodcalling.Values(int, int)': not all code paths return a value

In this way its showing error in VISUAL STUDIO 2013.

Comment: I think the error message is pretty clear. Not all code in `Methodcalling.Values` paths return a value. You've said `Values` returns an `int`. Where is returning an int?

Comment: you should return an integer if you have declared the function as an int

Comment: As a side note: Why do you use VS2013? Rather use VS2015 or VS2017RC

Comment: and you could check the string you are printing on the console :-) they should be swapped probably!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This error is because you have declared the function to return an `int`, but your function does not return anything.

Have a look at this link [here](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/csharp/csharp_methods.htm) for a reference on the function declaration in c#.

For a relief from the error, try adding `return 0;` to the end of the function.

```
public int Values(int num1, int num2)
{

    if (num1 > num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("num2 is large ");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("num1 is big");
    }

    return 0; // Return zero to the calling function.
}
```

Now you could call this function like this to capture the return value.

```
int TheReturnValue = Values(num1 , num2); //You will get 0 as value for TheReturnValue variable.
```

or change the `int` to void as in `public void Values(int num1, int num2)` if you don't want to return any values.

here is the usage:

```
public void Values(int num1, int num2)
{

    if (num1 > num2)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("num2 is large ");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.WriteLine("num1 is big");
    }
}
```

and **you could call the function(void Return Type) like this:**

```
 m.Values(a, b); //without assigning it to a variable
```

Since you are only writing to console using this function, void datatype would be the better option.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

You have to return an int value from the method as the method's signature defines a return type of `int`, and you are also calling

```
int result = m.Values(a, b);
```

which suggest that the method would return an integer but you have no return statement in your method.

You can modify the method like this if you don't want any integer to be returned.

```
using System;

class Methodcalling {

    public void Values(int num1, int num2) {

        if (num1 > num2)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("num2 is large ");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("num1 is big");
        }
    } 

    static void Main(string[] args) {
            int a, b;
            Methodcalling m = new Methodcalling();

            Console.WriteLine("enter a no.:");
            a = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            Console.WriteLine("enter a no.:");
            b = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

            m.Values(a, b);

    }

}
```